# merge multiple JSON documents in Oracle 19c

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

I have multiple JSON documents which are to be merged into a single JSON Document. Each of the document have same JSON structure as mentioned below and Keys are different.

```
{
  "KEY1":"VALUE1",
  "KEY2":"VALUE2",
  "KEY3":"VALUE3"
}
```

I have list of all document names as "col1,col2,col3,col4,col5" and one way of merging these documents is by using json_mergepatch, but it can merge at a time only two documents.
I used below query to merge these documents.

```
SELECT
json_mergepatch(col1,json_mergepatch(col2,json_mergepatch(col3,json_mergepatch(col4,json_mergepatch(col5,'{}' RETURNING CLOB) RETURNING CLOB) RETURNING CLOB) RETURNING CLOB) RETURNING CLOB)
FROM 
DUAL;
```

But this is generated manually, not sure how can I generate the json_mergepatch statement from the list of json documents names dynamically. I tried using REPLACE() and appended 'RETURNING CLOB)' at the end by n times where n is count of comma in the list.

Is there a better way to merge multiple JSON Documents than this, then please suggest.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output for this sample data. General words like "keys are different" or "list of json documents names dynamically" are not clear in the context of this question.